# Web User Control Causing Page Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webusercontrol

I came across a pretty weird issue. Some of my Web User Controls are causing the parent page which references it to get 404 page not found error.

Here is how I register it on the .aspx page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="DonationList"
Src="~/Controls/Donation/DonationList.ascx" %>
```

And the line where the user control is declared on the same aspx page:

```
<uc:DonationList ID="seenDonationListUC" runat="server" SeenInformation="Seen" />
```

If I remove the above line, I don't get a 404 error page anymore.

This is a small snippet of the user control class:

```
public partial class DonationList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public enum Seen
    {
        Unspecified = 0,
        Seen = 1,
        NotSeen = 2
    }
    public Seen SeenInformation
    {
        get
        {
            int temp = seenInformationHF.Value == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(seenInformationHF.Value);
            result = (Seen) temp;
            return result;
        }
        .....
```

Any idea on the possible causes of this?

Comment: You are certain that the src attribute is right?

Comment: @Abbath Yes, very certain of that. Checked letter by letter, case by case.

Comment: Then the only thing i can think of is that there is some error occuring on the usercontrol, which may be causing the redirect to the error page. Can you try replacing `SeenInformation="Seen"` with `SeenInformation="0"`, and the type of `public Seen SeenInformation` to int?

Comment: @Abbath Yes, that solved the issue. Thanks. I put a breakpoint on the Page_Load to ensure it hits, but I didn't think that the problem would be on the SeenInformation. Now this is weird. It has worked all the way until now. IntelliSense even provides me with the enum options. I guess the aspx page cannot find the proper reference for the enum at run time.

Comment: In your `SeenInformation` Setter, make sure that you set it to a numeric string value as this `Convert.ToInt32(seenInformationHF.Value);` will fall over if it cannot parse the string

Comment: Well, this is an old piece of code. I simplified it to what the problem needs before posting here. But proper validation is done to ensure it is numeric. Real thanks for your help, mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of your enum and subsequent enum value both are same "Seen". Try changing the enum name to something like SeenOptions. For example,

```
public enum SeenOptions
{
    Unspecified = 0,
    Seen = 1,
    NotSeen = 2
}
```

In this case your SeenInformation class will look like,

```
public SeenOptions SeenInformation
{
    get
    {
        int temp = seenInformationHF.Value == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(seenInformationHF.Value);
        result = (Seen) temp;
    }
    .....
```

And finally, your user control line on aspx page will be same as before.

```
<uc:DonationList ID="seenDonationListUC" runat="server" SeenInformation="Seen" />
```

I hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: Well, this ain't the issue actually. But renaming this old piece of codes to your naming convention is a brilliant idea. The issue is that, I actually have the enum declared in another class called CommonReference. Something like, public CommonReference.SeenOptions SeenInformation { .. }

But this used to work all along. Though problem is solved in one way, anyway.